# Pass content from before middleware to router in Silex

Tags: silex

I want to execute checks in the `->before()` middleware and pass results into the **route**.

Is this possible? The documentation seems to not mention anything.

```
$app->post( '/push/{id}', function( $id, Request $request ) {
    // access $foobar here
})
->assert( 'id', '[a-f\d]{24}' )
->before(function( Request $request ){
    // do something
    $foobar = 1;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

passing along data in the global $app variable works

```
$app['data'] = [];
$app->post( '/push/{id}', function( $id, Request $request ) use ( $app ) {
    // $app['data']['foobar'] = 1;
})
->assert( 'id', '[a-f\d]{24}' )
->before(function( Request $request ) use ( $app ){
    $app['data']['foobar'] = 1;
});
```

Comment: You can also use the *attribute* bag of the *request* object as so: ```$request->attributes->set('foo', 'bar');``` and then on your controller closure just ```$request->attributes->get('foo')``

Comment: @mTorres never answered but yes, you were obviously right :)